# Meaning of operator in ket bra notation in Hilbert space

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators

For simplest operator $\textit{M}$, I could write it as $|k\rangle\langle m|$.
\begin{equation}
\mathit{M} = |k\rangle\langle m|
\end{equation}
When operating on a state $|n\rangle$, I could write as:
\begin{equation}
\mathit{M}|n\rangle=|k\rangle\langle m|n\rangle=\langle m|n\rangle|k\rangle
\end{equation}
From that, I could interpret the operator M as transforming the state $|n\rangle$ to $|k\rangle$ with $\langle m|n\rangle$ as coefficient. However, how does $|n\rangle$ relate to $|k\rangle$ by the inner product $\langle m|n\rangle$ in Hilbert space? For example, the identity operator I is just:

\begin{equation}
\mathit{I}|n\rangle = \sum_{j=1}^{N} |j\rangle \langle j|n\rangle = \sum_{j=1}^{N} \langle j|n\rangle |j\rangle
\end{equation}

It is just projection of $|n\rangle$ on the basis $|j\rangle$. For $\langle m|n\rangle|k\rangle$, I have no idea how they are related in Hilbert space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your simple operator is a kind of projection onto the one-dimensional space spanned by $|k\rangle$.
The inner product $\langle m,n\rangle$ is the cosine of the angle between m and n scaled by their lengths.  If they
are all unit vectors, it is the cosine of the angle between them.  And if k is a unit vector, this cosine gives the length of $M |n\rangle$.  That is the relation you have asked for.  It is not exactly the usual projection, since you have introduced this angle with $|m\rangle$.

Comment: Your answer solved my confusion. Btw is it a typo that the length of vector k should be <m,n>?

Comment: How exactly is the operator introduced by OP, $M=\vert  k\rangle \langle m  \vert$, a projection operator? $M^2\neq M$ unless $m=k$. :/

Comment: I did not mean to say the operator was a projection operator, just that M of a vector yielded a kind of projection onto a one-dimensional subspace.  @Simon219 there is an art to being vague to a very precise degree: "gives" is actually a slightly vague word.  You can easily derive the precise formula yourself.  All I wanted to do was help clear up your confusion by providing "the big picture".  And you already clearly know how to write a projection operator's formula.

Comment: Your "projection" of a vector onto the subspace spanned by $\vert k \rangle$ would be non-zero even if the vector is orthogonal to $\vert k\rangle$. There is no earthly way in which this can be called a projection.

Comment: Your point is well taken, but in a curved universe, where I am living, it is hard to see straight, and one might think of this a kind of projection.  From certain skew angles.

Comment: Any references you can provide where this kind of projection is defined? In particular, a projection where $\mathbb{P}^2\neq \mathbb{P}$ or where the projection of an orthogonal vector is non-zero?

Comment: No, feel free to edit my post to omit the offending word, but there is a word for what you want, and it is "idempotent".  I didn't say it was idempotent.  In linear algebra, without a metric structure, there is no notion of projection.  Here of course there is.  I just didn't want to use the precise word "dyad" since I thought the OP was not asking for precise but antiquated concepts about linear algebra.  Then, there is "projective geometry" which uses projections, pencils, rays, etc., but has no metric structure and no notion of orthogonality.  BTW, the space of states is a projective space.

Comment: @josephf.johnson The [definition of a projection operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_(linear_algebra)) is an idempotent linear operator.  The operator $|k\rangle\langle m|$ is a map from the Hilbert space to the one-dimensional subspace spanned by $|k\rangle$ but because it fails to be idempotent, labeling it as a projection is simply not the correct terminology.  I restrict my edits of other users answers to the correction of typos, so perhaps you could consider making this correction yourself.

Answer (score 0):

- $\langle j \vert n \rangle \vert j \rangle$ is indeed the projection of $\vert n \rangle$ onto the vector $\vert j \rangle$ (assuming that $\vert j \rangle$ is normalized). The projection operator along $\vert j \rangle$ is $\mathbb{P}_j=\vert j \rangle\langle j \vert$ and you can see that $\mathbb{P}_j\vert n\rangle$ is indeed $\langle j \vert n \rangle \vert j \rangle$. You can verify that $\mathbb{P}_j=\vert j \rangle\langle j \vert$ is a projection operator by observing that $\mathbb{P}^2_j=\vert j \rangle\langle j \vert j \rangle\langle j \vert = \vert j \rangle\langle j \vert = \mathbb{P}_j$. That it is a projection operator along $\vert j \rangle$ is verified by observing that $\mathbb{P}_j\vert j \rangle = \vert j \rangle\langle j \vert j\rangle = \vert j \rangle$.
- There are many other intuitive verifications you can perform and see that this is a sensible definition of projection. For example, you can see that if $\vert j\rangle$ and $\vert i\rangle $ are orthogonal then $\mathbb{P}_j\vert i\rangle$ vanishes. You can also see that $\sum_j\mathbb{P}_j=\mathbb{I}$ where $\{j\}$ form a complete orthonormal basis. Proof: Consider that $m,n$ label the same orthonormal basis that is labeled by $\{j\}$. Then, we can write \begin{align*}\langle m \vert \sum_j\mathbb{P}_j\vert n\rangle=\sum_j\langle m\vert j \rangle\langle j \vert n\rangle= \sum_j \delta_{mj}\delta_{jn}=\delta_{mn}\implies \sum_j\mathbb{P}_j=\mathbb{I}\end{align*}
- So, to answer your question: As I said, $\langle j \vert n \rangle \vert j \rangle$ is indeed the projection of $\vert n \rangle$ onto the vector $\vert j \rangle$ (assuming that $\vert j \rangle$ is normalized). More geometrically, $\langle j \vert n \rangle \vert j \rangle$ is the vector in direction of $\vert j \rangle$ whose magnitude is equal to the inner product of $\vert j \rangle$ with $\vert n \rangle$.

Finally, I should mention that the operator $M$ you wrote is not a Hermitian operator and thus, it wouldn't be the kind of operator that shows up often in quantum mechanics, or at the least, it wouldn't  correspond to an observable.

Answer (score 0):

Little Base:

Suppose $\{|\phi_i\rangle\}$ form a basis in LVS $\mathcal{V}$. Then any vector $|\psi\rangle$ can be written as a linear combination of basis.
$$|\psi\rangle=\sum_i\langle \phi_i|\psi_i\rangle|\phi_i\rangle=\sum_ic_i|\phi_i\rangle$$

The combination $\{|\phi_i\rangle\langle\phi_j|\} $ form a basis for operators in LVS $\mathcal{V}$. Thus any operator can be written as
$$\Omega=\sum_i\sum_j|\phi_i\rangle\Omega_{ij}\langle\phi_j|$$
where $\Omega_{ij}=\langle\phi_i|\Omega|\phi_j\rangle$ are matrix element of the operator.

Now let's see How this operator acts on vector in this space.
$$\Omega|\psi\rangle=\sum_{i,j,k}|\phi_i\rangle\Omega_{ij}c_k\langle\phi_j|\phi_k\rangle$$
Using the orthonormality condition for the basis set
$$\langle\phi_i|\phi_j\rangle=\delta_{ij}$$
$$\Omega|\psi\rangle=\sum_{i,j,k}|\phi_i\rangle\Omega_{ij}c_k\delta_{jk}=\sum_{i,j}|\phi_i\rangle\Omega_{ij}c_j$$

Now we know from our linear algebra course that matrix multiplication is defined as
$$C=AB$$
$$c_{ij}=\sum_ka_{ik}b_{kj}$$

That looks like what we have found (just use the fact that $B$ has only one column). There is nothing new going on it's just simple matrix multiplication. It's just a generalization to all the $LVS$.

---

A Very good visualization for matrix multiplication and transformation can be found here.

[Essence of Algebra](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fNk_zzaMoSs&list=PLZHQObOWTQDPD3MizzM2xVFitgF8hE_ab) By 3Blue1Brown